# What is the name of the problem or technique used to quantify a given entity based on its properties?

Tags: terminology

I have the following idea:

Suppose a device D performing a set of tasks T1-Tn.
Each task Ti has 3 properties: time of execution(E), amount of memory needed(M) and priority(P).
`Ti: <E=1s, M=45kB, P=0>`.

Each of these properties is given a grade value ranging from 0-10 based on the property's value.
e.g.,: `Ti grades: <5, 2, 4>`.

Finally, I assign a score to each of the task by taking the sum of the 3 values (e.g., `5+2+4 = 11`)

**My question**: Can someone please provide me the name of a technique/scientific method that performs a similar operation?

Comment: Why not grading? As in grading a student. Your first step is like grading a test, your second step is like combining the grades to give a final overall grade.

Comment: There is no general method to achieve this, it is context dependent.

Comment: @YvesDaoust can you give me some related terms? It does not matter they from other fields/areas. I just need someplace to start looking.

Comment: No, this is just "common sense".

Comment: True, but it is always safe to follow a well established method/technique